# Find the number of off-parity inversions in a list of integers

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of integers, an off-parity inversion is an inverted pair that have different parities (one is even and one is odd).

I am to design an O(n log n) algorithm that counts the number of off-parity inversions. I understand how to count the total number of inversions in O(n log n) time, but I am unsure how to go about only counting the off-parity inversions.

Any suggestions to get me started?

This is a homework assignment, so just a nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a conditional expression in order to determine if the set is an off-parity inversion (i.e. contains one even and one odd integer).

If the condition is true (an off-parity inversion does exist) then you may add these into the total set or count. If not, then move on to the next set.

Using this conditional statement will not add any extra *significant* complexity to your algorithm as it can be done with the already existing information. Thus, if you do already have an O(n log n) algorithm, you may modify it with this condition without increasing its time complexity.